# Why does the same color scheme looks different in Android Studio than it does in PhpStorm?

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio, phpstorm

PhpStorm colors are much darker and not so readable as they are in Android Studio. Color codes are the same, but they way they look differs.

Is there something I can do to make colors look more like in Android Studio?

Here's example: 
[image: Different colors looks even if codes are the same]

You can see, that background colors look different, but codes are the same.

It is the same for every other color in every theme, even in default schemes like Darkula.

PhpStorm is just darker, and I want to know why is that and how to fix it.

Comment: are the devices different? there will be slight variations in colors when seen from different types of display.
have a look at this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42563/why-is-the-color-of-the-same-image-different-when-displayed-on-laptop-and-mobile

Comment: The problem is on the same device. As you can see in the screen shot I just added.

Comment: What versions those are? What OS? What GUI Theme you are using?

Comment: I've noticed this both on Windows and OSX. Does not matter what theme, if I use the same theme on both editors, colors will be differently reflected as you can see in the screenshot.